# How to import the MVGC Multivariate Granger Causality Matlab® Toolbox and use it?

Tags: matlab, import, causality

I want to study and use the *"MVGC Multivariate Granger Causality Matlab® Toolbox"* . For that I want to run a example for the same in Matlab. Can you tell me how to import this toolbox and use it with the help of one sample working example ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can [download](http://users.sussex.ac.uk/~lionelb/downloads/mvgc_v1.0.zip) it, extract the zip file, then run startup.m and see if you get no errors.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please answer the second part of my question too ? That is, can you give me a working example where the MVGC toolbox is used successfully. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did startup run with no error? I have a missing toolbox so so unfortunatly I cannot test example code

Comment: No it was throwing errors. The errors were about unidentified functions. I think the reason is the same as you mentioned, that is missing toolbox. Still trying things to work it out.